# OAuth2 with Spring MVC rest APIs

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am targetting to secure my REST APIs by custom OAuth Authorization server of my own (NOT google, facebook etc.) by using Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant. The user would pass the credentials over SSL and would get back the Access Token and Refresh token. I followed this tutorial - http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html

However, I have few questions -

1. 1- Is it good approach at the first place.
2. 2- User credentials in that tutorial are passed as query parameter.
   It's not the advisable approach. How can I make it a POST request.
3. 3- I want to store credential information in Database and implement
   custom authentication by validating the username/password from DB.
   (As opposed to the approach in above tutorial in which the
   credentials are stored in the file)

Please provide your insight. Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever implemented OAuth protocol with Google or FB before? I would suggest to use Google or FB because there are a lot of considerations which you wont be able to take into.

Comment: No, I haven't implemented it with Google or any other 3rd party authorization server before. And why I am not planning to do that is because I want to maintain the user database of my customers. For various business reasons. Can I somehow maintain the user DB and still make use of 3rd party authorization servers ???

Comment: or can I maintain the user information by user's Google/FB ids. If this is taken care of, I can use OAuth with Google/FB. Please share some good tutorial and code example if possible . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) IMHO , I think use Authorization grant instead of resource owner password grant. Which do the same , and more secure then the resource owner password grant.

2) I think you can follow [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/) tutorial to make authentication from DB.